# Find and replace duplicates in a string

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I have a problem, and can't figure out a soulution right now.

I have a string like this "abcd dfeg uyti lksh bxnm abcd uyti".

And i want to replace the duplicates with some other text (i use a function to generate random letters).

But there is a problem, that the new text is alerdy generated.

EXAMPLE INPUT "aaaa bbbb cccc bbbb cccc dddd eeee"

My output is like this "aaaa bbbb cccc aaaa eeee dddd eeee". which is wrong

But the output i want is like this "aaaa bbbb cccc ffff gggg dddd eeee"

I tried this code

```
function formatTEXT(text) {
    let words = text.split(" ");
    let replaced = new Set();
    let duplicatesFound = true;
    while (duplicatesFound) {
        const wordCounts = {};
        duplicatesFound = false;
        for (let i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
            const word = words[i];
            if (!wordCounts[word]) {
                wordCounts[word] = 1;
            } else {
                wordCounts[word]++;
            }
        }

        for (let i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
            let replacement = generateTags(lettersN);
            const word = words[i];
            if (!replaced.has(word) && wordCounts[word] > 1 && !wordCounts[replacement]) {
                words[i] = replacement;
                replaced.add(word);
                duplicatesFound = true;
                console.log(replacement);
            }
        }
    }
    return words.join(" ");
}

formatTEXT("aaaa bbbb cccc bbbb cccc dddd eeee");
```

but it still does not work, there are still some duplicates in here.

Comment: Can you provide some meaningful input/output, `uyti lksh bxnm` it not helpful.

Comment: What have you found out during debugging?

Comment: With `!wordCounts[replacement]` as condition this function's result strongly depends on what `generateTags` does. Without its implementation what do you expect us to say?

Comment: The generateTags function generates random text example ajss kdjf rufj etc.

Comment: What if your input is the word `"aa"`, repeated 27 times? Do you expect the random generator to replace the other 26 instances with `"bb"` or attempt to cycle through all lowercase letters? If the latter case is expected, what should the last instance be replaced with, since all lowercase letters would be exhausted at that point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function formatText(text) {
  let hashMappedString = text
    .split(' ')
    .reduce((previousState, currentElement) => {
      previousState[currentElement] = currentElement;
      return previousState;
    }, {});
  

  var newWords = '';
  for (let word in hashMappedString) {
    newWords += ` ${word}`;
    console.log(word);
  }
  return newWords.trim(); // to remove the space in the beginning
}
console.log(formatText('aaaa bbbb cccc bbbb cccc dddd eeee'));
```

// this code has the time complexity of O(n) + O(n) which is O(2n) which is O(n) by ignoring the constant

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is build a list while checking for duplicates, then join it back into a string:

```js
function formatText(text) {
    let words = text.split(" ");
    var newWords = []
    for (let i in words) {
        if (!newWords.includes(words[i])) {
            newWords.push(words[i])
        }
    }
    return newWords.join(" ")
}

console.log(formatText("aaaa bbbb cccc bbbb cccc dddd eeee"))
```

Output: `"aaaa bbbb cccc dddd eeee"`